# Plotly Histogram to contain individual data values

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

Is there a way to plot a plotly histogram such that each bin contains further details of individual data values?

An example is the google chart histogram:
[https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH4cp.png)

Comment: Like a stacked [bar chart](https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/#stacked-bar-chart)?

Comment: yes, but literally with text that I can customize for each element, such that when I hover over it I can see the customized text

Comment: check the following SO questions and answers: [SO question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646880/direct-labels-and-hover-info-to-be-different-in-plotly), [SO question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50919323/adding-additional-text-to-the-hovertext-label/50932965#50932965), and [SO question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50899374/add-secondary-description-in-axis-values-plotly/50913740#50913740). Those all talk about how to add text on hover. [Plotly Doc](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#bar-hoverinfo). This question is a possible duplicate.

Comment: but ultimately i'm doing trying to implement hovertext over a histogram, not a stacked bar chart, as per the examples in https://plot.ly/python/histograms/. A histogram usually has bins, and each data point is under a bin. I want to have a histogram with the each bin having a data point with hovertext.